# Android Retrofit 2 ошибка загрузки данных

Tags: android, retrofit

Пытаюсь получить данные, но в ответ приходит Null, хотя Postman выдает JSON

Метод загрузки:

```
public void LoadData(int id){
        Log.e("Start","start");
//        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Тут",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//        progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);


        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(APIUrl.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);

        Call<Smartphone> call = service.getSmartphone(id);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Smartphone>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Smartphone> call, Response<Smartphone> response) {
                Smartphone smartphone = response.body();
                Log.e("responce",smartphone.getName());

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Smartphone> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("Ошибка",t.getMessage());
                progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Ошибка:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
                      at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
                      at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:231)
                      at com.example.danilshik.testapplication.tabs.SmartphoneMainTab$1.onResponse(SmartphoneMainTab.java:84)
                      at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**ApiService**

```
@GET("smartphone/{id}")
    Call<Smartphone> getSmartphone(@Path("id") int id);
```

JSON:

```
{"smartphone":{"id":1,"name":"Samsung Galaxy S9","nameAlternative":null,"url":"https:\/\/www.kimovil.ru\/ru\/where-to-buy-samsung-galaxy-s9-eu","imagePath":"image\/smartphone\/thumb_123966_phone_front_medium.jpeg","brand":"Samsung","represented":"\u0444\u0435\u0432\u0440\u0430\u043b\u044c 2018","state":"\u041f\u0440\u043e\u0434\u0430\u0436\u0430","width":68.7}}
```

Может json не так сформулировал

UPD: 2 Класс

```
public class SmartphoneOne {
    public Smartphone smartphone;

    public Smartphone getSmartphone() {
        return smartphone;
    }
    public SmartphoneOne(){

    }
}
```

UPD: Класс 2.

```
public class Smartphones {
    ArrayList<Smartphone> smartphones = new ArrayList<>();

    public Smartphones() {
    }

    public ArrayList<Smartphone> getSmartphones() {
        return smartphones;
    }

}
```

Comment: Если есть сомнения в правильности POJO - стоило бы его показать.

Comment: Код 200, т. е все нормально

Comment: Класс слишком большой, более 100 свойств

Comment: Тогда понятно - у Вас должно быть 2 класса. Первый должен содержать всего одно поле `smartphone` с типом второго класса, а тот уже содержать все остальные свойства. В апи-интерфейсе нужно указать первый. В сети есть сервисы, которые облегчают жизнь в создании POJO, например: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org

Comment: Наподобии такого? код в конце вопроса

Comment: Да, оно самое...

Comment: Может лучше создать класс, который отвечает за список того класса и выбирать 1 элемент списка?Код добавил ниже

Comment: В Вашем json'е нет списка - парсинг провалится. Не усложняйте себе жизнь).

Comment: Очевидно не хватает POJO. Сделайте POJO в генераторе и выбирайте сколько угодно элементов в списке хоть 1 хоть все. хорошо бы вывести в лог код ответа. Если 200 - то POJO/ и добавьте аннотации для вывода одного поля. @Path вроде как